# PIC10f200 does it have NVRAM available for persistant changeable data?

Tags: pic

I have seen other PIC32xx have nvram available for permanent storage/retrival  of data.
Any knowledge of PIC10F200 has it as well ?
Any excample would be welcome.

I am looking for a way to store 4 bits of data (values 0-15) and change it at times.  Keeping the data at shutdown and restarts,  power off.

Comment: Here is [its datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001239F.pdf).

Comment: As @LongPham said, you just need to check the datasheet. A microcontroller without some form of program memory would be very unusual, though.

Comment: please correct your typos

Answer (score 1):

NVRAM (where programs are stored) is not accessible via register addressing.
Volatile RAM is accessible via indirect addressing of the **FSR**register - however it is only 5-bits length, and the RAM address space only extends 0x00 to 0x1F.

However, NVRAM **is accessible** by use of `retlw xx` instruction. Useful for look-up tables. A look-up table is read-only, and can only be set by re-programming the whole chip. An ASM example lookup subroutine below:

```
;test
#include p10F200.inc
    org 0
    movlw 0     ;initialize lookup index to top of table
    call lookup
    nop         ;Wreg contains table value
    nop


lookup:
    addwf PCL,f ;add an index to program counter
    retlw 'H'   ;1st data to look up (8-bits only)
    retlw 'E'   ;2nd data....
    retlw 'L'
    retlw 'L'
    retlw 'O'

    END
```